# SQL Server function running very slow

Tags: sql-server

I have this function that returns a single date and it takes 10+ min to run. Any clue why?  TMNCS have over 3 million records

SQL:
    select dbo.fn_TMNCS_BO_MaxDate

This is my latest rewrite
Function:

> ```
> ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_TMNCS_MaxDate]
> ()
> RETURNS date
> AS
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE @ResultVar as date
>   SELECT @ResultVar= Max([DateOfData]) FROM dbo.TMNCS
>   RETURN @ResultVar    
> END
> GO
> ```

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked with other columns?

Comment: For starters, scalar functions are notoriously poor from a performance perspective. An inline table valued function is almost always orders of magnitude faster. But in this case I would venture that you don't have an index on DateOfData? Can you share the table definition including indexes? Perhaps you are storing this as a varchar? That would be a huge issue.

Comment: . . . One single solution is not to use Scalar function.

Comment: TMNCS is a view of another table that have 70 million records.  DateOfData is part of a primary key, so it is index. 

You did guess correctly, I'm using a scalar function.

Comment: There was no guessing, you posted the scalar function. And just because that column is part of a primary key does NOT mean the index is covering for this query. Again...what is the datatype? There are so many reasons this could be suffering from performance issues but we are not seeing details to be able to answer confidently.

Comment: datatype is datetime.  I always thought if it's part of the primary key, it would be index.

I did change the query to:
select top 1  @ResultVar= max(DateOfData) over () from dbo.TMNCS   This did greatly speed it up.

Comment: Does it take 10 minutes for a single invocation are you using this function inside another query which takes 10 minutes? Do you have primary key on the view? Also, is it the "end part" of primary key?

Comment: @Draco but is it the left hand column of the index or not, we have no idea and can't help you until you give more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can tolerate assuming the newest row in the table having the max date and if you have a clustered index (esp an identity)
then you can try this :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_TMNCS_MaxDate]
()
RETURNS date
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ResultVar as date
  SELECT TOP (1) @ResultVar=  [DateOfData] FROM dbo.TMNCS ORDER BY TMNCS_ID DESC --Assuming this is the Clustered index/ identity col
  RETURN @ResultVar    
END
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Well 3 million records is not extremely large, but it could be large enough to at least slow down a function trying to find the max value.

I can suggest adding an index to the `DateOfData` column:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON dbo.TMNCS (DateOfData);
```

This should let SQL Server very quickly find the max value for this column.  Assuming the index is a B-tree, all SQL Server would have to do is to go the far left/right side of the tree and read the value there.

Disclaimer: If you require the max value of some column in a table, in the context of a regular SQL query, then please look into using `MAX` as an analytic function.

Comment: . . . Yes definitely this will help, but OP using scalar function which causes the issue. However, the real solution is to avoid function for such cases & use something like  window function instead.

Comment: @YogeshSharma If the OP is just using this scalar function in a query, when in fact he should just be calling `MAX` directly, then I agree with you.  But, maybe he actually needs this function in some other context.

Comment: Or even worse they may have the column as a varchar and it has to make 3 million implicit conversions. If that is the case then no indexing is going to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use window function instead :

```
select t.*,
       max(DateOfData) over () as max_date
from dbo.TMNCS;
```

Comment: This assumes that the OP was calling the scalar function from an ordinary query, and not in some other context.